# View SQL statement history sent from applications?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In Oracle SQL Developer, is there a way to see the SQL statement history sent from applications?

For example, I'm using the **Oracle.DataAccess.dll** library in my ASP.Net application to talk to my database. Is there a way to see the history of SQL statements (in raw text) sent to the database from it, from within Oracle SQL Developer?

Comment: May you want something like this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8828/how-do-you-show-sql-executing-on-an-oracle-database

Comment: @stickybit That looks like what I want to do, but it appears to only pertain to "currently executing" SQL. Also, I tried running the accepted answer's query in SQL Developer, and got a "table or view does not exist" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, no.

Unless - you have enabled tracing for your ASP.NET's application session in the database.

Then, if you have access to the trace file - which will be on the server, and you'll need to get down to where SQL Developer can read it, then we can show you what's in the Trace file.

[image]

There are OTHER places to find SQL's that have been execute, but you won't find an audit trail for every executed for each application.

So my advice, using [TRACING](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_trace.htm#TGSQL94999).